# Theos %log doesn't work

Tags: theos

Here is a theos demo, it can hook successfully in iOS10.2, but I cannot find the %log info in syslog, why?

```
%hook SBApplication
-(id)displayName {
  %log;
  return %orig;
}
%end
```

Answer (score 1):

Logging has been increasingly less stable in recent iOS versions for whatever reason and because of that most people use a different approach for debugging. My personal go-to is to create a [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?language=objc) with title / message set to the debugging information I want to see.

To display it on the highest view controller, you can use:

```c
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```